# discord.py add_role() gets missing permission error despite having adminstrator role

Tags: python, discord.py

I've made a couple of roles to play with, the admin role (which the bot has) and a "timeout" role which is levels lower than the admin role. I have checked and redone the bot's permissions, gave it administrator and used an alt account that is not the owner of the server to test. none of the above yielded any results and I'm still stuck with permission denied. here is my block of code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    stopchecks = False
    if message.author not in moderationwhitelist:
        
        if message.mention_everyone:
            await message.reply("off to timeout with you")
            timeout = get(message.guild.roles, name="timeout")
            await message.author.add_roles(timeout)
            stopchecks = True
```

PS: the client variable is from client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
and the intents variable is discord.Intents.all()

PPS: i have searched around stack overflow for answers, and tried the suggested solutions for them, but none seemed to work

expected results were that the timeout role would be applied to the message author,
actual results were that role was not applied, and bot received permission denied error

Comment: show the imports such that the code has a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).